# area of rose curve?

Tags: integration, curves, polar-coordinates

Using a double integral, find the area inside the petals of the rose curve $r=2\sin2\theta$ and outside the circle $r=1$.

I have done work on this and am thinking that the period would be pi, therefore that being the upper limit of integration. I am guessing that the lower one is $0$.

I ended up getting the answer $\pi$. That was for the rose curve part. Does anyone know where to start with the circle part? Is my lower limit of integration correct? I started my integral by using only the letter r.

Comment: When I attack a problem like this, my first step is to be sure that I am *visualizing* the problem correctly.  Unfortunately, what this means is that computer software must be used to convert the mathematical expression into a precise image.  Personally, I use [Latex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX), which (among other possibilities) affords the graphical plug-ins of PSTricks, PGF-Tikz, and/or Asymptote.  There are certainly other free software possibilites (that I am unfamiliar with).  One example might be Geogebra.  ...see next comment

Comment: See also [Graphing Software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_information_graphics_software). Also, going forward with your future mathSE postings, graphs or geometric diagrams embedded in the posting can be very helpful.  See also the tail end of [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) as well as [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33909/recommendation-enhance-the-mathse-html-markdown-help-article-re-images).

Answer (score 4):

The curve $r=2\sin2\theta$ is symmetrical by the $x$-axis and the $y$-axis. Therefore, the area you want to obtain is $8A$, since the area cut by $x$-axis and $y=x$ as $A$.

Then let's get the value of $A$. Since the first quadrant is $0\le\theta\le\frac\pi4$. and the solution of $1\le2\sin2\theta$ is $\frac\pi{12}\le\theta\le\frac{\pi}{4}$.

So $A=\int_{\pi/12}^{\pi/4}\frac12(r_1^2-r_2^2)d\theta$.($r_1=2\sin2\theta, r_2=1$). Then...

$$
A=\int_{\frac\pi{12}}^{\frac\pi4}\frac12\left((2\sin2\theta)^2-1^2\right)d\theta
=\frac12\int_{\frac\pi{12}}^{\frac\pi4}(4\sin^22\theta-1)d\theta
=\frac12\int_{\frac\pi{12}}^{\frac\pi4}(2(1-\cos4\theta)-1)d\theta\\
=\frac12\int_{\frac\pi{12}}^{\frac\pi4}(1-2\cos4\theta)d\theta
=\left[\theta-\frac{\sin4\theta}2\right]_{\frac\pi{12}}^{\frac\pi4}
=\frac{2\pi+3\sqrt3}{12}.
$$

So, the answer is $8A=\frac{4\pi+6\sqrt3}3$.